# Java - a performance tweak dilemma

Tags: java, performance, rest, web-services

Problem - We have a page that calls 6 web services (rest). Takes a really slow time to load.

Dilemma: Which will help improve performance more? Option 1 or option 2?

Option 1: Front end executes asynchronous calls on the 6 web services. The web services by the way are not dependent on each other.

Option 2: Front end calls one wrapper endpoint web service method. The new wrapper endpoint calls the six web services in the back end and consolidates the output. It also calls the web services asynchronously.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure perf is the only consideration here.  Option 1 requires securing six times as many front-doors.

Comment: So you'd choose option 2?

Comment: Option 1 should be faster,as you have one hop less

Comment: @RobAu how is it one hop less? seems roundtrip will involve travel to web server and application server

Comment: `UI <> Rest Facade <> Rest` or `UI <> Rest`. First is extra